# C - Dynamically initializing arrays

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to find the equivalent of int myArray[n], except I don't know what n is without input.

Is the following code supposed to work? (I need to use kmalloc instead of malloc).

```
int * pages;
//... later, after we find out n...
pages = (int *)kmalloc(npages * sizeof(int));
```

Debugging using gdb, the value pages[0] doesn't seem to be 0 - is this expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Memory is not initialized, you just get a pointer to your chunk of memory.

You'll need to [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) to initialize it:

```
memset(pages, 0, npages * sizeof(int));
```

Also, unless I'm mistaken `kmalloc` takes a [second parameter](http://people.nl.linux.org/ftp/pub/anoncvs/kernelnewbies/documents/kdoc/kernel-api/r2415.html), the type of memory to allocate.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc` returns a pointer to some location on the heap that it has allocated for your array.  It does not initialize that memory.  You can use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to have the memory be initialized (set to zero), or you can use `memset` after you allocate the memory and set the memory to zero yourself.

Since you are using `kmalloc`, you'll probably have to use `memset`; I don't believe there is a `cmalloc` for allocating initialized memory in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the kernel function [kzalloc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kzalloc.html):

```
int * pages;
pages = (int *)kzalloc(npages * sizeof(int), GFP_KERNEL);
```